# Send the values of recycleview settext as intent

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have a recycleview in a card layout, the cards have 3 values set with a company array, I'm trying to send those values as an intent. But for some reason everything I try the intent ends up sending null

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
    //companyList= new ArrayList<Company>();
  //heres where the textviews get there values set
    final Company company = companies.get(i);
    viewHolder.textViewHead.setText(company.getCompanyTitle());
    viewHolder.textviewDesc.setText(company.getCompanyType());
    viewHolder.textViewNumber.setText(company.getCompanyNumber());
    viewHolder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ///send these to nodes them attach the officers, get both in nodes and send to myview
            companylist = new ArrayList<Company>();
            //here are my ateempts try and send the values as intents
            Company company1 = companies.get(i);
          //  view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), Nodes.class));
            Intent skipintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Nodes.class);
            skipintent.putExtra(KEY_NAME, company.getCompanyTitle());
            skipintent.putExtra(KEY_NAME,viewHolder.textViewHead.getText().toString());
            skipintent.putExtra(KEY_TYPE, company1.getCompanyType());
            skipintent.putExtra(KEY_NUMBER, company1.getCompanyNumber());
            //  view.getContext().startActivity(skipintent);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Companyname", company.getCompanyTitle());
            bundle.putString(KEY_TYPE, company1.getCompanyType());
            bundle.putString(KEY_NUMBER, company1.getCompanyNumber());
          // bundle.putParcelableArrayList("Companyselected", companylist);

            skipintent.putExtras(bundle);
            new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(company1.getCompanyNumber());
        }
    });

}
```

And here is my activity where I am trying to receive it

```
      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_nodes);
    //Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
  //  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //textViewNodes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewNodes);
     //  ArrayList<Company> recList = this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Company");
   // companyList= new ArrayList <>();
    ArrayList<Officer> officerArrayList = this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Officer");
  //          ArrayList<Company> companyArrayList = this.getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("Companyselected");

    Intent skipintent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (null != skipintent) { //Null Checking
        Company company = new Company();

        String companyTITLE = bundle.getString("Companyname");
        String companyNUMBER = skipintent.getStringExtra(company.getCompanyNumber());
        String companyTYPE = skipintent.getStringExtra(company.getCompanyType());
        company.setCompanyNumber(companyNUMBER);
        company.setCompanyTitle(companyTITLE);
        company.setCompanyType(companyTYPE);
        companyList.add(company);
        Log.d("help", "onPostExecute: " + company.getCompanyTitle());

    }
    Log.d("meme", Arrays.toString(new ArrayList[]{companyList}));
```

here is the end of retrivefeed, I think I should send the values of the textviews here im not sure how

```
  try {
                  JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray itemsAraay = object.getJSONArray("items");


                officerList = new ArrayList<Officer>();


                Log.d("borkofficer", "onPostExecute: " + itemsAraay.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsAraay.length(); i++) {
                    Officer officer = new Officer();
                    JSONObject jsonObjectNew = itemsAraay.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonObjectNew.optString("name");
                    String role = jsonObjectNew.optString("officer_role");
                    String appointed_on = jsonObjectNew.optString("appointed_on");
                    //JSONArray.put(jsonObjectNew);
                    officer.setOfficerName(name);
                    officer.setOfficerRole(role);
                    officer.setOfficerAppointed(appointed_on);
                    officerList.add(officer);
                    Log.d("borkofficer", "onPostExecute: " + officer.getOfficerName());


                    Log.d("borkofficertitle", "onPostExecute: " + officer.getOfficerRole());
                }
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("Officer", officerList);


                //Intent skipintent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Nodes.class);


                Intent intentofficer = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Nodes.class);
                intentofficer.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Officer", officerList);


                Intent intentofficer1 = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Nodes.class);
                intentofficer1.putExtras(bundle);

                //  context.startActivity(intentofficer1);
                  intentofficer.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  intentofficer1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intentofficer);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

update im trying to bundle up the value and send in a intent but its still coming up null in the other activity is it because of the other intent im trying to send?
          class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask {

```
        private Exception exception;


        protected String doInBackground(String... numbers) {
            companylist = new ArrayList<Company>();

            Company company = new Company();

            String companynumber = numbers[0];
            String companytitle = numbers[1];
            String companytype = numbers[2];
            company.setCompanyTitle(companytitle);
            company.setCompanyType(companytype);
            company.setCompanyNumber(companynumber);

            companylist.add(company);

            Bundle bundle1 = new Bundle();
            Intent skipintent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Nodes.class);
            skipintent.putExtra(KEY_NAME, companytitle);
            skipintent.putExtra(KEY_NUMBER, companynumber);
            skipintent.putExtra(KEY_TYPE, companytype);
            skipintent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Companylist", companylist);

            skipintent.putExtras(bundle1);

            Log.d("connect", "onPostExecute: " + companytitle.toString());
            Log.d("connect", "onPostExecute: " + companytype.toString());

            try {
                URL url = new URL(API_URL + companynumber +"/officers");
                Log.d("connect", "onPostExecute: " + companynumber.toString());

                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                try {

                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "uG5RCz7yWRZNKaMlkQRzUPXY1NpN0SRrb8mKSZ-0");


                    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
                    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);

                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");

                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();

                    return stringBuilder.toString();

                } finally {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            if (response == null) {
                response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
            }
            Log.i("INFO", response);
            //does this store?

            try {
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray itemsAraay = object.getJSONArray("items");


                officerList = new ArrayList<Officer>();


                Log.d("borkofficer", "onPostExecute: " + itemsAraay.length());
                for (int i = 0; i < itemsAraay.length(); i++) {
                    Officer officer = new Officer();
                    JSONObject jsonObjectNew = itemsAraay.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonObjectNew.optString("name");
                    String role = jsonObjectNew.optString("officer_role");
                    String appointed_on = jsonObjectNew.optString("appointed_on");
                    //JSONArray.put(jsonObjectNew);
                    officer.setOfficerName(name);
                    officer.setOfficerRole(role);
                    officer.setOfficerAppointed(appointed_on);
                    officerList.add(officer);
                    Log.d("borkofficer", "onPostExecute: " + officer.getOfficerName());


                    Log.d("borkofficertitle", "onPostExecute: " + officer.getOfficerRole());
                }
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putParcelableArrayList("Officer", officerList);



                //skipintent.putExtra(KEY_NUMBER, company1.getCompanyNumber());
                //  view.getContext().startActivity(skipintent);
                //Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
               // bundle.putString(KEY_NAME,);
                //bundle.putString(KEY_TYPE, companylist.get(1).getCompanyType());
                //bundle.putString(KEY_NUMBER, companylist.get(1).getCompanyNumber());
                //company1.setCompanyTitle(;
                //company1.setCompanyNumber(KEY_NUMBER);
                // company1.setCompanyType(KEY_TYPE);
                // companylist.add(company1);
                // bundle.putParcelableArrayList("Companyselected", companylist);

                //skipintent.putExtras(bundle);
                Intent intentofficer = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Nodes.class);
                intentofficer.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Officer", officerList);


                Intent intentofficer1 = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), Nodes.class);
                intentofficer1.putExtras(bundle);

                //  context.startActivity(intentofficer1);
                  intentofficer.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                  intentofficer1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                context.getApplicationContext().startActivity(intentofficer);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Inside the activity, try to extract values with same keys as were used in adapter. Use

```
  String companyNUMBER = skipintent.getStringExtra(KEY_NUMBER);
  String companyTYPE = skipintent.getStringExtra(KEY_TYPE);
```

instead of

```
  String companyNUMBER = skipintent.getStringExtra(company.getCompanyNumber());
  String companyTYPE = skipintent.getStringExtra(company.getCompanyType());
```

**UPDATE**

2. To start activity inside the AsyncTask, pass data as a constructor parameter: `new RetrieveFeedTask(company.getCompanyName())`.

```
  private String mCompanyName;

  RetrieveFeedTask(String companyName) {
    this.mCompanyName = companyName;
  }
```

and then use it as usually to put in the intent:

```
intent.putExtra(KEY_NAME, mCompanyName);
```

**UPDATE 2**

As an alternative, you can pass data in the `new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(company1.getCompanyNumber(), company1.getCompanyTitle(), company1.getCompanyType())` method and use them in `doInBackground`:

```
String doInBackground(String... data) {
  String companyNumber = data[0];
  String companyTitle = data[1];
  String companyType = data[2];

  // ...
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... I copied the code and it works fine. Please, check: 1) How and where you actually start activity? 2) Does the `RetrieveFeedTask` changes `companies` of the adapter?

Comment: I just updated it, I think im making a mistake because im sending the intent at the end of retrievefeedtask, Im not sure how to send to include the textviews in that intent

Comment: @Mrtcupz, you can temporary keep all data you need in your `RetrieveFeedTask` instance (pass it in as a constructor parameter, for example) and then put it in intent.

Comment: new RetrieveFeedTask().execute(company1.getCompanyNumber(), company1.getCompanyTitle(), company1.getCompanyType());

Comment: but im not sure how to access that at the end and send the intent

Comment: All data you pass in `.execute()` are elements of array which is the only varargs parameter of the `doInBackground` method. I've added sample of usage.

Comment: thank you for all of these replies, im getting the values over and they are there but when I send them to the other activity its coming up null are my two intents colliding?